# making an app using python with django library but the server not responding

Tags: python, django

i have installed django using command prompt and do coding on visual studio code by installing python. it is showing the django installed successfully but after the project setup , it does not show any kind of output . instead it is showing ' this site can't be reached . server refused to connect.'

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

For your local server to run you need to the following :

- Make sure your virtual environnement is launched
- launch your server as follow : python manage.py runserver

You should see something like that ;

```
Django version 4.1, using settings 'mysite.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
```

Go to http://127.0.0.1:8000/

Please read and do the following official tutorial : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/intro/tutorial01/ it explains everything